# Curl version on command line is different to PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, ubuntu-12.04, curl

I've got PHP version `5.5.21-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2` running with Apache2 under Ubuntu 12.04

When I run `phpinfo()` it shows the curl version as `7.22.0`

When I run `curl --version` via the command line - it shows the version as `7.34.0`

How do I get PHP to use the newer version? I need a curl version `>=7.24.0` for my needs

Edit: ok - I've half solved the problem - this is my `curl --version` output:

```
curl 7.39.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
```

So I have curl 7.39 - but libcurl/7.22

How do I update libcurl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`libcurl` is not `curl`](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-libcurl.html). To update `libcurl`, use your OS's package management utilities.

Comment: Thanks. I can see I need "vivid" libcurl. Any idea how to install that via the command line? http://curl.haxx.se/download.html